# Having a database table that should stored a single record or row in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I don't know if I'm going about this the right way, but in my application I have two(2) tables that seems like they both are going to store a single record each.

Conceptual view of tables:

**Institution(holds information of the school)**

**Academic(holds academic information of the school)**

```
institution
-----------
name,
motto,
logo,
etc

academic
----------
school-year-start
school-year-end
current-period
current-semester
```

The long term goal of my app is to have in place a multi-tenancy feature that supports separate databases. In idea it is an application for secondary schools.

Now, Is it a best practice to have such tables in your system? If so, how do one handle the situation wherein a user tries to add a new record; assuming a record already exists.

Comment: Why can't you store everything in one table?

Comment: Read a lot of the principle of separation of concern, but If you advise and won't cause much trouble in the future I can give it some consideration.

Comment: I wouldn't see any issue with it - the only thing I'd pick up on is that school year start and end dates might change year on year so if you want to store them from previous years, you'll want another table.

Comment: Splitting tables is for when you plan to expand in the future. You really should split tables because data separation is always important. But you also need columns to build foreign keys if you plan to query them both at the same time or relate the data.

Comment: @clearshot66 from what I have how would advise I design both tables?

Comment: guys what do you advise on the situation wherein a user tries to create a new record.

Answer (score 0):

Given what you're looking to capture, my opinion:

**institution_information:**

- school_name (varchar)

  address (varchar)

  type (enum, two year four year masters only)

  style (enum online, on campus, mixed )

  slogan (varchar)

  logo (varchar if image path

**academic_year:**

- school_id (primary key, not auto inc, from other table)

  year_start (date)

  year_end(date)

  semester_type (enum tri-mester,    two semester year)

  not sure what those last two are?

You should be designing tables to be dependent on a primary key, with a foreign key to relate tables

Primary Key Column <--- data column

^---- data column

Comment: Sorry for responding late. I get what you are trying to do, but what if a user try to insert another record?

Comment: It's a college per college basis for each row. Each college would be a new row. You shouldn't be adding more than one college per row and you shouldn't be adding more than one year/semester information per row in that table

Comment: Sorry maybe I didn't fully explain better. I plan on it being a multi-tenant app that supports separate databases. Now when the app is deployed each school that chooses to use the application will have their data store in a separate database, but should use the same application.

Comment: Database tables aren't designed to store one row lol, if you plan one database per college/institution you should have more than one table still for various data groups

Comment: I building what is like a school management for secondary schools, and the application requires that each database should how record relating to a specific school. How do you advice I go about this?